# ArangoDB CSV Upload as one entry in colection

Tags: csv, arangodb

I'm trying to upload a csv file into an Arango collection. I can successfully use arangoimp to upload the csv file, BUT it uploads each row in the csv as an entry in the collection.

I want to upload the whole csv file as one array into a collection.

For example, if my CSV file were:

`a,b,c
d,e,f`

using `arangoimp --file "csv_file" --collection CSV --collection-create true`

I get a collection called CSV with 2 entries, one for `[a,b,c]` and one for `[d,e,f]`

I want the collection to have 1 entry that looks like `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]` as to keep the whole file together. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to import a file that is in CSV standard. For example:

```
"FieldOne","FieldTwo","FieldThree"
"a","b","c"
"d","e","f"
```